# Update many documents by pushing an object to an array field when id field matches the id field in the object

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, push, insert-update

Ok that question doesn't sound very clear. I will try to explain.
I have a collection of F1 drivers that contains an array field to store the points earned from each race.
I use a web form to submit the full result of a given race that contains the race_id, race_name, and a positions array that contains the driver_id and points earned as an object for each driver.
I now need to update each driver in the collection with their result from this race by matching the driver id with the id in the object array.
Ultimately; I will also need to update the total_points for each driver, but that can wait for now.

```
// The handler for my web form
function handleRaceResultSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let positions = [{id: null, points: 25}, {id: null, points: 18},{id: null, points: 15},{id: null, points: 12},{id: null, points: 10},
        {id: null, points: 8},{id: null, points: 6},{id: null, points: 4},{id: null, points: 2},{id: null, points: 1},
        {id: null, points: 0},{id: null, points: 0},{id: null, points: 0},{id: null, points: 0},{id: null, points: 0},
        {id: null, points: 0},{id: null, points: 0},{id: null, points: 0},{id: null, points: 0},{id: null, points: 0},];

    const eventID = parseInt(document.querySelector('#event-select').value);
    const eventName = document.querySelector('#event-select').textContent;
    const selectGroup = document.querySelectorAll('.select-group');

    selectGroup.forEach((driver, index) => {        
        positions[index].id = parseInt(driver.value);
    })

    const raceResult = {
        event_id: eventID,
        event_name: eventName,
        result: positions
    }

    updateDriverResults(raceResult);
}

// Post result to the endpoint
const updateDriverResults = async (data) => {
    fetch('driver-points',
    {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then(res => {return res.json()})
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
}

//My endpoint and Mongoose query
app.post('/driver-points', express.json(), (req, res) => {

    Drivers.updateMany({
        'id': { $in: [ req.body.result.id ] },
    },
    {
        $push: {'results': {
            'event_id': req.body.event_id,
            'event_name': req.body.event_name,
            'points': req.body.result.points
        }}
    })    
    .then((result) => {
        res.send(result);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    })
})

// The model
import { mongoose } from "mongoose";
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const driversSchema = new Schema({
    id: Number,
    driver_name: String,
    totla_points: Number,
    results: Array
});

const Drivers = mongoose.model('driver', driversSchema);

export { Drivers };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to give you a rough idea on how to solve this, I have prepared a sample in [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rUOIeygh9bF) that shows how you can use an update with aggregation pipeline to perform complex updates for documents. Let's assume that there are 3 drivers in your collection with `_id` 1, 2  and 3. Drivers 1 and 2 already have some points from the first race whereas driver 3 does not have any results up to now.

In the next race, drivers 1 and 3 reached points, so these two drivers should be updated so that

1. The `results` field is initialized as an empty array if it is not present yet,
2. The newly awarded points should be added to the `results` array,
3. The driver `_id` is removed from the `results` field and
4. The `total` field should be updated with the total number of points.

The sample assumes that there is an array with the `_id`s of the drivers that should be updated (`[1, 3]`) and also an array that contains the results:

```
  [
    {
      _id: 1,
      race_id: 2,
      race_name: "Spa",
      points: 7
    },
    {
      _id: 3,
      race_id: 2,
      race_name: "Spa",
      points: 3
    }
  ]
```

The following update statement is used to perform the updates:

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: {
    $in: [
      1,
      3
    ]
  }
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      results: {
        $ifNull: [
          "$results",
          []
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      results: {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$results",
          {
            $filter: {
              input: [
                {
                  _id: 1,
                  race_id: 2,
                  race_name: "Spa",
                  points: 7
                },
                {
                  _id: 3,
                  race_id: 2,
                  race_name: "Spa",
                  points: 3
                }
              ],
              cond: {
                $eq: [
                  "$$this._id",
                  "$_id"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "results._id"
  },
  {
    $set: {
      total: {
        $sum: "$results.points"
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

Please use this sample as a starting point that you can integrate into your mongoose environment.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! When I hard code the values it works perfectly. So all I need to do now when I handle my form submit is to post two arrays, one containing the driver ids and one containing the race result then substitute the arrays within the query with these?

Comment: You're welcome; yes, all you need to do is to integrate the arrays (one for the filter in the `$match` and one for the actual positions in the `$set`).